# Add a custom word to a cross reference in LaTex

Tags: latex

Good morning!

I've been searching for a time but I can't reach a solution to my problem. I'm writing my master thesis, and I want to add custom words to my references, I mean, if I want to ref the only table in my document (`\label{table:test`} for example), I usually do `\ref{table:test}`, getting as a result just a clickable number 1.

However, I need to set a global option in order to, always I refer to a table, for example, I get `{custom word} 1`(1 for the first table). This custom word surely will be `Table`, but I can desire to use `Figure`(in English) or `Imagen` (in spanish), for ref figures.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cleveref` package will automatically add the correct words and adapt to the language of your document:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{content...}
\label{key}
\end{figure}

\cref{key}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to custom this word? I mean, choose the word `imagen`, for example, instead of `figura`?

Comment: @Á.Garzón you can change the words with `\crefname{figure}{imagen}{plural}
\Crefname{figure}{Imagen}{Plural}` (replace `plural` with whatever is the plural of `imagen`)

Comment: Thanks you! I misread something in your answer, so I had a wrong result, but now it works!